# I have troubles connecting a Mediatek smartwatch to Ubuntu Linux. Anyone has clues?

Tags: usb, mediatek

I own a Chinese smartwatch, it has no specific brand but when I connect it to my pc it states that it has a Mediatek chipset. In the past, I was able to connect it to the USB port to download and upload pictures and audio. Lately, I am unable to do it anymore. The USB cable works, since I use it for my phone, too. The internal micro SD card works (I tried it on my pc, and it is read), and the smartwatch itself can read and write on it. But when I connect it to my pc I cannot see anymore its content. I have Ubuntu Linux 20.

The command dmesg returns this output:

```
[19228.820861] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 1.00
[19228.820864] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[19228.820866] usb 3-1: Product: Product
[19228.820868] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek Inc
[19228.820869] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 53381008440835f
[19228.826901] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[19228.827033] scsi host7: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[19229.833884] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MEDIATEK  FLASH DISK           PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[19229.834221] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[19229.839868] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] 15759360 512-byte logical blocks: (8.07 GB/7.51 GiB)
[19229.842866] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[19229.842869] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[19229.845866] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page found
[19229.845871] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[19229.885879]  sdf: sdf1
[19229.898869] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
[19230.213880] scsi 7:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to dead device
[19230.213887] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 136 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 15 prio class 0
[19230.213898] scsi 7:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to dead device
[19230.213902] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 264 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[19230.213920] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 2, async page read
[19230.213963] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 2, async page read
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution here:
https://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?t=632002

Since it's in Italian, I'll repost the part that did the trick here:

In file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules

I commented the line:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="0e8d", ATTR{idProduct}=="0002", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"
```

Turning it into:

```
# ATTR{idVendor}=="0e8d", ATTR{idProduct}=="0002", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"
```

After that, I can access the files on the smartwatch again